# i am adding add_action inside a model of wordpress plugin but it is showing error unexpected identifier

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-plugin-creation

> this is my model file

```
class customactionsModel {

     function getMessagekey(){
       $key = 'customfunction'; if(is_admin()){$key = 'admin_'.$key;}return $key;
     }

    function __construct(){
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_admission_form', 'admission_form');
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_admission_form', 'admission_form');
    }
    function admission_form() {
     //call hook;
        echo "ljdlf";
        wp_die();
    }
 }
```

> i am facing error that is:

```
error - unexpected identifier "add_action", expecting "function" or "const" in Standard input code
```

Comment: try move you actions to the top of you file
 
`<?php  
           add_action( 'wp_ajax_admission_form', 'admission_form');
           add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_admission_form', 'admission_form');`

And remove it from construct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class definition is not correct. your not defining the scope of the functions, and you need to refer back to the class in the add action

```
class customactionsModel {

 public function getMessagekey(){ //May needs to be a private function
   $key = 'customfunction'; if(is_admin()){$key = 'admin_'.$key;}return $key;
 }

  public function __construct(){
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_admission_form', [$this,'admission_form']);
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_admission_form', [$this,'admission_form']);
  }
  public function admission_form() {
   //call hook;
      echo "ljdlf";
      wp_die();
  }
}
```